HTTP Error code for Mutual TLS Handshake Certificate Error
We're working on an integration that will allow and external 3rd party too call our APIs..
The third party controls the governance of the how our APIs should respond, and have stipulated that we must return an HTTP 403 error when the client calls with a missing, invalid or expired mTLS certificate.
Note, that this is not in a browser scenario. We have a technical service of some description outside out network calling into an API endpoint exposed by our system.
We have implemented an mTLS listener on an Azure App Gateway, and have observed that the default behaviour for this is to return a 400 Bad Request.
We are of the view that this cannot be reconfigured, so can i just check this is a common understanding?
More fundamentally though, I'm looking to understand if there are challenges we should highlight in respect of industry standards for HTTP Error codes in this instance.
Fundamentally, sending a 403 here feels wrong, but I'm keen to add some evidence to that feeling.

You are absolutely right, Fundamentally, sending a 403 is indeed wrong- Here is your MS backed evidence- -   HTTP response codes in Application Gateway

Thanks. I was aware of the above link, but also conscious that App Gateway is very vendor specific. Are you aware of any platform/vendor agnostic standards that stipulate this? The RFC around this isn't too prescriptive, and our third-party have pointed to examples where they get a 403 from other services/providers (IIS is one they cited, but I can't confirm this)

You're correct that Azure App GW behavior is vendor-specific, in this case MS default response of 400 Bad Request for mTLS certificate issues reflects Microsoft's implementation and this is the standard for AppGw Microsoft follows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/http-response-codes#400--bad-request


Absolutely. Thanks. I was wondering if there were any industry guidelines that stipulated this as standard for all provides. RFCs around this don't seem prescriptive.

You are right, when implementing mTLS on an Azure Application Gateway, the default behavior for handling issues related to client certificates (such as missing, invalid, or expired certificates) typically results in an HTTP 400 Bad Request response. This is a standard behavior of the Application Gateway when it cannot properly negotiate mutual authentication as per HTTP response codes - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn
Returning an HTTP 403 Forbidden status code in this scenario may not align with standard practices. The HTTP 403 status is generally used to indicate that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it, which is not the case when the client certificate is missing or invalid; instead, it is more appropriate to return a 400 status indicating a bad request due to client-side issues.
References-

HTTP response codes in Application Gateway
Analyzing Incoming Web Services Request Telemetry

